Why is my image URL not saving to my SQLite database?
In my code in my Livewire component's controller the path is showing correctly in the flash message and the image file is saved correctly to the default folder. What am I doing wrong with creating the database entry? The other variables are entering correctly and the column type for the image URL is varchar, but just stays NULL.
public function createNewUser()
{

    $validated = $this->validate([
        'name' => 'required|min:2|max:50|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
        'image' => 'nullable|sometimes|image|max:1000'
    ]);

    if ($this->image) {
        $validated['image'] = $this->image->store('images');
    }

    $user = User::create($validated);

    //Assign recruit role for new user
    $user->assignRole('Recruit');

    //Reset input fields
    $this->reset(['name', 'email', 'password', 'image']);

    //
    request()->session()->flash('success', 'User creation succeeded.' . $validated['image']);
}

public function changeRole()
{
    $validated = $this->validate([
        'id' => 'required|min:1|numeric',
        'role' => ''
    ]);
}


what is stored in the variable $this->image? and what does $this->image->store('images') return?

@Raptor $this->image stores the image I'm uploading to the drive in the images folder. The return is the path of the file in the images folder with a randomly generated name and appended file type as a string.

for simplicity, why don't you just save the image path in DB instead?
